# Does resoling change a climbing shoe's fit?

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing-shoes

If climbing shoes are resoled, will they fit differently afterward? If so, in what way does it change (narrower, shorter, tighter, looser, etc..)?

Comment: Not really an answer, just a thought: it might depend on how you walk. For example, my walking destroys the outer extremities of the shoes' soles. If I use a pair of shoes for too long, they get so used that I can't even stand with my feet and soles parallel to the ground - thus stressing my ankles and knees. Resoling would change this in a good way :)

Comment: @Akabelle: you don't typically walk much (barely at all, really) in climbing shoes.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt yes, I see now I answered having "trekking shoes" in my mind. so my comment is useless indeed :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have had several shoes resoled, and each one fit pretty much just as they did before the resoling.  No adjustments or breaking in necessary, as all the shoes were well seasoned, and the resoling had no perceptible effect on fit.

Comment: Not having to break in a shoe again is the best reason to re-sole proactively (before the rand gets damaged).

Answer (score 5):

Not unless they did a really bad job.

Shoe size starts with the sole.  It would be really hard to even sew in an upper to a wrong sized sole. If you told the cobbler you want less width they could stitch in a bit but not very much.

It will take  a bit of time to break the sole in but not nearly as long as the original break in period.